How to fix (unattributable) conversion sources?
Starting a few weeks ago, my GA4 conversion report began reporting nearly all conversions to the (unattributable) / (unattributable) traffic source.
My session data seems good - the regular mix of organic / direct / paid / etc. But I don't understand how session data could be right but conversion attribution to be unattributable.
Any thoughts as to how I might fix this?

Have you recently enabled User Provided Data Collection? The big blue button that appeared in the data collection settings in admin.
Try turning off User Provided Data Collection, or you can change your reporting identity back to "Observed" instead of "blended", that should resolve the issues.
Admin -> Data collection and modification -> Data Streams -> Select your web stream -> (google tag) Configure Tag Settings -> Allow user-provided data capabilities -> TURN OFF allow user provided data capabilities.
OR
Admin -> Data collection and modification -> Reporting Identity ->. Switch to "Observed" if the above doesn't fix it.
